# Website only loads halfway on mobile

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently working on a coming soon page for a customer. And when I try to enter the webpage on a mobile only half of the page loads.

nelsee.net is the website.

Here is my code.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans');
body {
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1106433/pexels-photo-1106433.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 12em;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 6em;
}

.content h3 {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

#demo {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.social-icons {
  margin-top: 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-icons a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .footer {
    margin-top: 7em;
    position: relative;
  }
  .header {
    margin-top: 7em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--Bootstrap-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--FontAwesome-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--Custom CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <!--Custom Scripts-->
  <script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

      // Get todays date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
        minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      // If the count down is finished, write some text
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
  </script>
  <!--ICO-->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imgs/icon.png" />
  <!--Title-->
  <title>Coming Soon</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-12">
        <div class="header">
          <h1>nelsee.net</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>We are currently working on our full website.</h3>
          <p id="demo"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
          <p>follow us:</p>
          <div class="social-icons">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000077515899"><i style="font-size: 2em;" class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/nsstoilova/"><i style="font-size: 2em;" class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Firstly I thought that its because of the viewport meta so I tried changing that.

It might have something to do with the bootstrap container?

I would add a codepen but I'm too lazy to do so :D

Alsoo.. if you run the stackoverflow snippet you will see how it looks like in landscape mobile mode.. Any way to fix that too?

[Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPrWs.jpg)

[Half loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTsj3.jpg)

Comment: Did you try to check your console logs? How did you debug?

Comment: I checked my console on Mozila Web Developer also I tried using the debugger there.. Nothing came up.

Comment: The script you placed in your `<head>` is attempting to write to `#demo` at a time the element, most likely, has not yet been added to DOM. You should run that script when the page has loaded. Not saying that's why your page breaks, but it's clearly a problem. But there's a good chance it's what's at fault, since `null` doesn't have a `.innerHTML` property.

Comment: I've put it right before the body end. But it still breaks on mobile.

Comment: @PeterBrezitski have you cleared the cache on your mobile? Simplest way would be to load the page in incognito mode. Mobile browsers typically cache loaded pages and resources, to save bandwidth. And clearing browser cache on mobiles is cumbersome, to say the least.

Comment: Just did.. same problem.. I'll attach a photo to the post.

Comment: What's in `css/style.css`? And what does *"on mobile"* mean? Device version, browser version, OS version.

Comment: As of now, you haven't added a proper [mcve] to your question. If the problem happens on a specific device/browser/OS combo, please clarify. And remember most devs here won't open your website. Because they consider your question needs to be autonomous in order to be helpful to future users with a similar problem. If it needs your website to be understood, the moment the website changes, the question will no longer be relevant and helpful for others.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new and I'm not good at explanations. By saying "On Mobile", I mean on my S9+ android browser. Runs Android Oreo. It's the same on Google Chrome for android aswell.

Comment: Also it's a bit hard to reproduce the problem since I can't on CodePen or even by shrinking down my browser. I've added 2 screenshots of the issues I'm experiensing on my Android phone.